# Android Studios R file continues to disappear

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-xml

Hi ok so I'm making an app using android studios and this has happened a lot but I've been able to fix it. So there are times (not often but they still occur) where I'm editing the xml of one of pages or I add something in a java file that when I run my code (using Android Studios not Eclipse) and then all of the sudden my R.class file gets deleted in front of my very own eyes. (Like Im literally watching the hierarchy as I run the code and the file just goes poof.) Usually I've fixed it by copy and pasting my R.class file from the backup I keep but this time I've tried that and it keeps deleting it. I don't know what went wrong but please someone help me. Thank You

(PS In my preview for all of my activities everything is fine and there are no red lines indicating errors. It was when I added images from my drawable I think that this problem started. )

Errors in Logcat per request:

```
07-12 16:44:50.872      183-183/? E/﹕ invalid crash request of size 4 (from pid=26208 uid=0)
07-12 16:44:51.143  26801-26801/? E/Diag_Lib﹕ Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open    handle to diag driver, error = 2
07-12 16:44:51.143  26801-26801/? E/Sensors﹕ sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
07-12 16:44:51.144  26801-26801/? E/Sensors﹕ sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
07-12 16:44:51.224  26801-26807/? E/Sensors﹕ sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
07-12 16:46:26.463      183-183/? E/﹕ invalid crash request of size 4 (from pid=26801 uid=0)
07-12 16:46:26.764  27476-27476/? E/Diag_Lib﹕ Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
07-12 16:46:26.764  27476-27476/? E/Sensors﹕ sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
07-12 16:46:26.765  27476-27476/? E/Sensors﹕ sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
07-12 16:46:26.898  27476-27482/? E/Sensors﹕ sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
```

Messages say

```
Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDebugResources’.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process ‘command ‘/Users/…(my file path)../Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt” finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Some of my xml that call on the image:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="org.example.sudoku.MMW"
    android:id="@+id/mm_w"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <TextView android:text="@string/mmw_info" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/manip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Corresponding Java:

```
package org.example.sudoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MMW extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mmw);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mmw, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey instead of providing negativity why doesn't someone actually respond. I find it that a lot of people like to be negative and not explain a reason for their negativity. Provide constructive criticism, else don't be rude please. For those of you who aren't and actually help thank you but for those that just dislike and not provide anything constructive then please delete your accounts cause stack overflow is a community of people who help one another not harm.

Comment: Check out all your resource files. Even the **smallest error** in xml files is harmful. As well as **invalid characters** in file names.

Answer (score 0):

Never I mean**never** copy or paste out touch the r.java file. This happens when they're is problem with your xml is normal there is nothing to be worried about . to solve this clean and build the project once and it will tell you the error fix that error, r.java is a file that android creates is a reference to all your views that android creates in hexadecimal format

Comment: I just right now tried to clean it and rebuild and in the hierarchy the folder for r just deleted completely and it says error in crunching one of my pictures and then it said see the log and my logical had a crazy amount of red. Is there anything else I need to be doing? (PPS it worked before but for some reason now it doesn't work)

Comment: The logcat isn't even showing anything anymore. Now the messages just say "No resource found that matches the given name ..." for all my pictures but the preview shows them on their corresponding activity so I don't understand

Comment: Also says Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDebugResources’.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process ‘command ‘/Users/…(my file path)../Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt” finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Have you put the image on the drawables folder

Comment: Yes they're all in there but now for some reason my drawables split up into three folders for hdpi, ldpi, and mdpi. It wasn't like that before. Previously it was all one drawable folder. (Ps now my images brought in are in the mdpi folder)

Comment: That's correct behavior actually it should be in all the folders, how are you accessing it can you post all the code

Comment: It's kind of a lot. I can post like one of my xml files that call on one of the images. If you need it's corresponding java class I can post that too. Else if you need all the code to help if you are willing I can send you a zip file of the project via email or something?

Comment: But thats kind of a lot to ask